# tmux logging history of detached panel

Tags: linux, ubuntu, security, logging, tmux

I  working on collecting data of users login time and used commands on linux server. Maybe somebody know how to get tmux command history without closing session?

If session was closed, history go proper to tmux-client-XXXXX.log

but we usually run something in tmux, detached from session [without close it!] and back to this session in next few days. Only when work is done we close session, so we dont see in history file used commends when they are used, but just after session was close.

Anyone have same problem, can You point me what to search to solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

I may be mistaken, but tmux just opens a new shell (probably bash or zsh), doesn't it? So, if you want to access that sessions history, you just have to look at the shell history. That would be usually the `history` command.

Comment: first I think it is true, but I take a look on old commend :/
I stored history of users by ssh key, I dont see working-tmux command in this file, and when i use command history also dont see :/

Comment: from tmux man
             history-file path
                     If not empty, a file to which tmux will write command prompt history on exit
                     and load it from on start.